# Postgres Copy from Variable with CSV data

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, active-record-query

I know you can run a copy command like this from a file:

```
"COPY zip_codes FROM '/path/to/csv/ZIP_CODES.txt' DELIMITER ',' CSV;"
```

I'd like to copy csv data from a ruby variable so I can do like so

```
"COPY zip_codes FROM '#{csv_data}' DELIMITER ',' CSV;"
```

Comment: I believe nobody understood your question, if it is a question.

Comment: I edited it to make it clearer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not possible with the SQL [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) command. `COPY` only copies from a *file* or *STDIN*.

You can either write the content of the variable to a file or pipe it via STDIN. Only makes sense for more than a couple of rows.

---

I think I misunderstood your question before the update, you probably don't need this:

The file path can not be exchanged like other data items, and you can't use a prepared statement for that. Build the *whole* statement before executing or resort to dynamic SQL with a server-side function like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_cp(_file text)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format($$COPY zip_codes FROM %L DELIMITER ',' CSV$$, $1);
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_cp('/var/lib/postgres/sync/myfile.csv')
```

[`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) requires Postgres 9.1 or later.