# plpgsql, how to store variable into file

Tags: windows, postgresql, cmd, plpgsql

I want create a custom variable (string) that contain data from different tables.
I can't do it in one query (special order to store, and dynamic columns).

Is there a way to store the variable into file?

Or using command line to save the result of one variable into file?

Comment: you mean to export and store the result of query into file? Please clarify.

Comment: And "command line" is supposed to be the shell? Or psql? And how does plpgsql come into this? Please clarify your question, show the code you have (even if it's not working) and add your version of Postgres (as always).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of tag `plpgsql` I assume that you are executing some queries inside a plpgsql function and the result saved in a variable should be send to a file.

In plain SQL you can save a text in a file using a `copy` command, something like this:

```
copy (select 'some text') to 'c:\data\sample.txt';
```

In a plpgsql function you should use `execute` command to select a value of a variable, example:

```
create or replace function copy_some_text_to_file(filename text)
returns void language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    var text:= 'some text';
begin
    execute format($fmt$
        copy (select '%s') to '%s'
        $fmt$, var, filename);
end $$;

select copy_some_text_to_file('c:\data\sample.txt')
```

If you want to save to file a variable with multiline string, you can use `regexp_split_to_table()`:

```
create or replace function copy_some_text_to_file(filename text)
returns void language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    var text:= 'first line\nsecond line\nthird line';
begin
    execute format($fmt$
        copy (select regexp_split_to_table(e'%s', e'\n')) to '%s'
        $fmt$, var, filename);
end $$;
```

Note, that the string cannot contain a single quotation mark, which must be properly escaped. While in the first version you can replace `'%s'` with `%L` (as Erwin suggested), you cannot do that in the second version.

Read more:

- [COPY command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html)
- [Executing Dynamic Commands](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Comment: It must be format(`$fmt$copy (select %L) to %L$fmt$, var, filename);` to properly escape the literals. Like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16991854/939860

Comment: Thanks, is there way to break line using your script? I already tried E'', \n

Answer (score 1):

Executing SQL from the Linux shell you can easily redirect the result to a file:

```sh
postgres@db:~$ psql mydb --tuples-only -c 'select 1' > /path/to/myfile.txt
```

Or execute SQL for a file:

```sh
postgres@db:~$ psql mydb -t -f /path/to/myscript.sql > /path/to/myfile.txt
```

Or from within psql:

```sh
\o /path/to/myfile.txt
\t
SELECT 1;
\o
```

Everything is explained in [the manual for psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html).